# how to get week number of a year where sunday as the first day of a week in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

how to get week number of a year where sunday as the first day of a week in javascript, also the fixed year number?

e.g. `2012-12-31` should have the same year number and week number with `2013-01-01`.

I found a snippet to do this, but the week is always start from monday not sunday, how to fix it?

```
exports.getYearAndWeek = function(d) {
    // Copy date so don't modify original
    d = new Date(d);
    d.setHours(0,0,0);
    // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
    // Make Sunday's day number 7
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay()||7));
    // Get first day of year
    var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(),0,1);
    // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
    var weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7)
    // Return array of year and week number
    return [d.getFullYear(), weekNo];
}
```

Comment: Programmers usually write code, not search for something and ask another people to fix what they found. Have you tried to do your work yourself?

Comment: @zerkms I tried on this line `var weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7)` never works, stange.

Comment: What you've tried? I see that you've just copied the line as is. Have you tried to understand what this code does?

Comment: @zerkms I don't know what's the matter if someone have more experience to solve this question rather than solve it myself. you don't know how to answer just get away.

Comment: _"2012-12-31 should have the same year number and week number with 2013-01-01"_ - What? How can a date in 2012 have the same year as a date in 2013? How can a date in December have the same week number as a date in January?

Comment: @zerkms I am asking is also a way to learning.

Comment: @zerkms You show me how to use stackoverflow? how to ask this question, edit it if you can ask a better question. Don't just vote close and pretend to be a god.

Comment: @guilin 桂林: the better question is the one that shows your effort. I've asked you: "Have you tried to understand what this code does?". Have you?

Comment: @zerkms of course I tried. I have got the answer, proved that my question describe correctly. What's your point? if someone try to understand this code, he must have understand it, so he should not ask it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first week of a year, for weeks starting with Monday, is the first week that has a Thursday in it, as your code suggests.

If your weeks start with Sunday, the first week will be the first week containing a Wednesday.

If the year starts on Thursday to Saturday the days until Sunday will be in the last week of the previous year. If the year starts on Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday, the last Sunday of the previous year is the beginning of the first week of this year.

Comment: So I should do it like this, `d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3 - d.getDay());`, right?